# How to use vlookup function in ms excel without getting REF error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

hey I need help getting a value from different  sheet named "unaddedraw" by comparing a key column of the two sheets.I've used the formula "=VLOOKUP(B3,'[unaddedraw.xlsx]unadded full'!$A$4:$A$60832,6,FALSE)" but it gives me a REF error.How to solve this?

Comment: Change the `A$4:$A$60832` to `A$4:$F$60832`.

Comment: Don't use `VLOOKUP` which is notorious for creating problems, use INDEX/MATCH instead https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

Comment: Please show data set so we can further assist as well as the result you would like to have.